# Change Pen thickness using textbox User input

Tags: c#, winforms, pen

I want to change the line thickness Pen draws in Picturebox with user input who puts a number in the textbox. i don't know how to assign the input number to a Pen.

I have a method that gets location input from user to draw lines it looks like this under a button:
drawLine(colorChange);

For Pen thickness i have int penThickness = 0;
and i get the value by parsing
penThickness = int.Parse(penThickness.Text);

in the button i have the code
drawLine(colorChange); // this works and it draws lines between user input location
If i try drawLine(colorChange, penThickness)// to also get the pen thickness value along with the pen color i get overload problems

Solution: The piece of code for pen thickness had to be also in the method i'm calling to draw the line.

Comment: Post the actual code that causes the issue, not these small tidbits inside a paragraph.

Comment: In order to improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some guidelines to follow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please pay particular attention to the section titled **Help others reproduce the problem**.

Comment: you said you are having overload problems. Make sure you have created `drawline` method with the signature that also accept thickness as a parameter along with the color.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav. That was the issue. It is fixed now, the method can now call the correct drawline function